# string & reference return type c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, return-value

My uml says that the getter method getName is of type string & and const 
(getName(): const string &)
so in my .h file I wrote

```
public:
std::string & getName() const;
private:
std::string name;
```

and in my .cpp file

```
string & Class::getName() const
{
return name;
}
```

when I try to compile my .cpp file I get an error saying :  invalid initialization of reference of type `std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}` from expression of type `const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}`

If I try to change the return value from name to &name, I still get an error. I'm not sure how to fix it. Help please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to return a `const` reference:

```
const std::string& getName() const;
```

Otherwise you are granting non-const access to an object's data via a `const` method.

Answer (score 3):

When your member function is `const`, it only has `const` access to member variables.

So, you cannot bind `name` to a non-`const` reference inside that function.

**Your return type will have to be `const std::string&`.**